# Java debugger interface (JDI) - How to set a breakpoint

Tags: java, debugging, jdi

I am asking because I am unable to find anything using Google.

I want to debug `org.Example`. I want to set an breakpoint and then resume the VM to execute till the breakpoint. `org.Example` is just a dummy main function.

So I do have my VM, but I didn't find a way to get to a `Location`object. I reduced the problem to not being able to get a `ReferenceType`object.

My problem: I have a simple command line debugger with a launching connector

I set the classpath to `"<Project_DIR>\out\artifacts\javaDebugger_jar\*"` for the VM, where the program to debug should run. In the `javaDebugger_jar` folder are multiple JAR files, one of those containing the `org/Example.class` file.

If I call "vm.resume()" the program will execute. I guess before the "resume" the Main Class is not loaded.

So what is the procedure here? How to make sure the class is loaded or do I need to set a breakpoint on method entry for a specific class (which I know how) and then in set the breakpoint as on method entry in class "Example" the breakpoint can be set.

I am asking because that seems to be so stupid. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

So after thinking for a while this behaviour is expected.

I am trying to set a breakpoint before any (non jdk) classes are loaded. This simply is not possible.

I need to watch for the methd entry of the main method ans then set the breakpoints. This means:

`org.Example` is loaded. All class files on which this class depends are loaded.

**I am aware this is only true for classes which are directly dependant. I am not sure this is working for JDBC drivers, which are loaded via a `Class.forName` or other things.**

For me this solution is sufficient. If you have an addition how such classes (classes which are dynamically loaded) are found, please answer this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "class prepare request" via the virtual machine's event request manager to get notified when classes are prepared:

```
    EventRequestManager erm = machine.eventRequestManager();
    erm.createClassPrepareRequest().enable();
```

This will give you an event when any class is prepared on the VM, regardless of how it is loaded. You can set a filter so that it only notifies for specific classes, if you like. You may wish to set the suspend policy if you rely on this in order to set a breakpoint when the class is loaded.